# What is exclamation mark dot (!.) operator in C#

Tags: c#, operators, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I suspect it has something to do with the nullable reference types introduced in C# 8, but I cannot find the documentation on this operator.

I stumbled upon it in the dotnet/corefx repo in linq code:

```
_enumerator = GetEnumerable(0)!.GetEnumerator();
```

`GetEnumerable` returns `IEnumerable<T>?`, so I suspect this will have somthing to do with the nullable `?`.

But what does the `!.` actually do?

Pointing me to some documentation would be the best for me, some concise tutorial would be also appreciated (but I tend to like official documentation more). No tutorial I have found in my quick search used this operator in any way.

Comment: Some call it the dammit operator, but the official name is the null-forgiving operator.